# Taking out bypass_ujvc hint in 12c converting update to merge statements

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, merge

Hi I've been tasked with getting rid of the bypass_ujvc hint from a number of update statements as it's no longer supported in Oracle 12c, I have decided to replace the update statements with a merge statement, unluckily one of these update statements has a returning clause and a bulk collect, so i'm unsure how to approach this as a merge statement does not use a returning clause. Any advice is much appreciated. The query is below.

```
  UPDATE    /*+ bypass_ujvc */ (SELECT caco.surr_id,
                                       caco.lead_item_yn,
                                       caco.case_reference,
                                       caco.logically_deleted_y
                                FROM TABLE (CAST(l_cc_surr_id AS db_surr_id_type_tab)) cc 
                                JOIN case_contexts caco ON (caco.cc_surr_id = cc.COLUMN_VALUE)
                                JOIN cases cas ON (cas.REFERENCE = caco.case_reference )
                                WHERE caco.logically_deleted_y IS NULL
                                AND cas.status IN ('INP', 'TOS'))
  SET logically_deleted_y = 'Y'
  RETURNING         surr_id, lead_item_yn, case_reference
  BULK COLLECT INTO l_caco_surr_id, l_lead_item, l_all_cases;
```

Comment: You could look at a `forall` approach. If I get some time later I'll put together an example.

Comment: thanks William, that might be a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach using `bulk collect` and `forall` would look something like this:

```
begin
    select caco.surr_id, caco.lead_item_yn, caco.case_reference
    bulk collect into l_caco_surr_id, l_lead_item, l_all_cases
    from   table(l_cc_surr_id) cc 
           join case_contexts caco on caco.cc_surr_id = cc.column_value
           join cases cas on cas.reference = caco.case_reference
    where  caco.logically_deleted_y is null
    and    cas.status in ('INP', 'TOS');

    forall i in 1..l_caco_surr_id.count
        update case_contexts
        set    logically_deleted_y = 'Y'
        where  surr_id = l_caco_surr_id(i);
end;
```

You might want to put that in a loop with a `limit` clause, but this should give the general idea.